# Criar atalho com python

Tags: python, windows, back-end, windows-10, software

Eu gostaria de saber como faço para criar um atalho do meu próprio script .py usando Python.

Ou seja, o meu código cria um atalho dele mesmo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por desencargo: **a)** você quer criar o atalho de um arquivo USANDO a linguagem Python ou **b)** você quer criar o atalho DO SEU script Python para executá-lo ao iniciar o Windows? A pergunta "*criar atalho com Python*" sugere que você quer a opção A, mas no texto você coloca "*criar um atalho do meu .py*", que sugere a opção B.

Comment: Veja se [isso](https://pbpython.com/windows-shortcut.html) ajuda

Comment: A sua pergunta está um pouco dúbia. Na primeira parte se refere à um ATALHO. Já na segunda parte, nos dá a impressão que desejas inserir um script `.py` na pasta de inicialização do Windows - talvez - querendo que o referido script inicialize todas as vezes que o sistema for inicializado. Sugiro editar sua questão deixando mais clara sua intensão.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **O código abaixo deve rodar com privilégios administrativos**.

Caso a pergunta seja como fazer com que um script python crie um link de si e o envie para dentro da pasta de inicialização global no sistema operacional windows:

- primeiro seu script terá que descobrir o [caminho a pasta a inicialização do OS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/f54bf562-237f-4970-95d6-debcd0ad0e98/what-is-api-to-get-public-folder-directory-path?forum=windowssdk).
- depois terá que criar um link para si e o colocar na pasta de inicialização.

Para descobrir o caminho para pasta de inicialização é possível fazendo uma pesquisa no registro da máquina em que o script estiver sendo executado e extrair a entrada.
A chave do registro ["HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders"](https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/windows-10-shell-folders-paths-defaults-restore/) contém os caminhos para os *shell:folders* que são paths especiais no ambiente windows. Dentre esses paths se encontra o caminho para [*shell:Common Startup*](https://windowsreport.com/windows-10-startup-folder-location/#:%7E:text=To%20do%20that%2C%20press%20the,in%20Run%20and%20click%20OK.) que a pasta de inicialização do para todos os usuários do Sistema Operacional.

Ciente disso o programa deverá então se conectar ao registro via a função [`winreg.ConnectRegistry()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#winreg.ConnectRegistry) na chave [`winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) e com a função [`winreg.OpenKey()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#winreg.OpenKey) abrir a chave "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Shell Folders" e então contar o número de valores dessa chave com a função [`winreg.QueryInfoKey()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#winreg.QueryInfoKey) e então os enumerar com [`winreg.EnumValue()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/winreg.html#winreg.EnumValue) e salvalos em um dicionário `shell`.

Para criar o link faça com a função [`os.symlink()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.symlink) e passe como parâmetros a origem o caminho absoluto para o global [`__file__`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3147/#id67) e como destino `shell["Common Startup"]` que é valor contendo o caminho para a pasta de inicialização do sistema operacional.

```
import os
import winreg

shell ={}

with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE) as reg:
    with winreg.OpenKey(reg, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders") as key:
        for i in range(winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[1]):
           nome, val, _ = winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
           shell[nome] = val

os.symlink(os.path.abspath(__file__), f"{shell['Common Startup']}\\teste.py")
```

Caso a pergunta seja como fazer com que um script python crie um link de si e o envie para dentro da pasta de inicialização particular do usuário que execute o script no sistema operacional windows, o processo é mesmo mas muda alguns detalhes muda a [chave de registro a ser pesquisada](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/how-to-redirect-user-shell-folders-to-a-specified-path-by-using-profile-maker-ed6289ae-1f9c-b874-4e8c-20d23ea65b2e) e nome do valor passa a ser apenas `Startup`.

```
import os
import winreg

shell ={}

with winreg.ConnectRegistry(None, winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER) as reg:
    with winreg.OpenKey(reg, "Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\Shell Folders") as key:
        for i in range(winreg.QueryInfoKey(key)[1]):
           nome, val, _ = winreg.EnumValue(key, i)
           shell[nome] = val

os.symlink(os.path.abspath(__file__), f"{shell['Startup']}\\teste.py")
```

> Caso a pergunta não seja sobre se autocopiar ao criar o link apenas troque o cominho de origem pelo caminho do arquivo que queira criar o link.

Answer (score 0):

Fazendo uma busca no google, esse tipo de arquivo realmente não é trivial de se mexer - é um formato binário -  e exige codigo especializado para respeitar os campos, etc...

Existe uma lib opensource para trarar esses arquivos, que inclusive tem bindings para Python -mas tentei instalar aqui e é Python2 ainda. De qualquer forma, na pasta de projeto da lib tem a documentação dos arquivos .lnk  (pode ser mais fácil arrumar os arquivos .py dela para Python3 do que re-implementar a leitura  e escrita desse tipo de arquivo - https://github.com/libyal/liblnk/blob/main/documentation/Windows%20Shortcut%20File%20(LNK)%20format.asciidoc